# What would void Start() be in pseudocode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pseudocode

I'm writing my unity code into pseudocode but can't find any examples of void Start() of void Update() in pseodocode

Comment: `function Start() { doSomething(); }      function Update() { doSomethingEachUpdate(); }`  -voila! pseudo code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "pseudocode".

Most people just mean that it is generally simpler and more natural-English-looking, with relaxed syntax when compared to "real" code.

Generally in that case I would use something like `run_at_start` and `run_30_times_a_second` to cover what Unity does.

However if you have a specific definition of "pseudocode" that you have to adhere to then  it may not have something that is applicable.